# IDEA's terminal input git branch order, there is an error?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, terminal

When I input git branch order in IntelliJIDEA's terminal, it will have an error like this:

```
$ git branch
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

and sometimes when I input git branch, it doesn't display any branches, like this:

```
~
(END)
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Try in your session:

```
set TERM=msys
```

That should help getting rid of the "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" warning.

Add:

```
export LESS=-JMQRiFX
```

That will avoid `(END)` at the end of a short output.
See [`man less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less).
The `-F` or `--quit-if-one-screen` option is the one important here.

If this work, those could be set in `~/.bashrc`, in order for IntelliJ IDEA to reuse/set them when opening a new bash session.